# Cabal install works but cabal list does not find package

Tags: haskell, package, cabal

I have separately installed cabal in I:\cabal and ghc in I:\ghc folders. I had a previous installation of Haskell-Platform which did not work and I had to uninstall it. But there is a folder named `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\cabal` which has many packages (total size 705mb).

Now when I try to install a package, I get error message:

```
>cabal install easyplot
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
cabal: installdir is not defined. Set it in your cabal config file or use
--installdir=<path>
```

So, I do following and it installs ok:

```
>cabal install easyplot --lib --installdir="C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\cabal"
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
```

There is now an easyplot package in folder `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\cabal\packages\hackage.haskell.org`

But when I try list command, it is shown as not installed:

```
>cabal list easyplot
* easyplot
    Synopsis: A tiny plotting library, utilizes gnuplot for plotting.
    Default available version: 1.0
    Installed versions: [ Not installed ]    <<<<<<<<<<<<< NOTE
    Homepage: http://hub.darcs.net/scravy/easyplot
    License:  MIT
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of cabal-install are you using?

Comment: I installed cabal.exe from `cabal-install-3.0.0.0-x86_64-unknown-mingw32.zip` file.

Answer (score 3):

Good catch! I opened up an issue on the `cabal` tracker.

With `cabal-install` 3.0 and beyond, packages you "install" are put into the `store` rather than the packagedb, and then made available through tools by being listed in the global `ghc environment` file. The `list` command isn't updated to be aware of this workflow, and only lists packages which are in the standard packagedb.

Comment: 3.4.0.0 seems to have the same problem. Do you have a link to the open issue so we can track I?